# C/C++: Why the localtime display incorrectly in respect of its timezone?

Tags: c++, c, timezone

I found that a strange behavior on C language recently but no idea why this happen.

when I use setenv(), set the TZ to **GMT+1**.
the output of the local time will be one hour **less** than UTC time. (see the output)

actually, when I set the TZ to **GMT-1**.
the output of the local time will be one hour **more** than UTC time.

This doesn't make sense. And if you don't believe, you can try the below code in C.
Anyone knows this strange behavior? is it a bug?

**Code:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
       time_t now;
       struct tm *local;
       setenv("TZ", "GMT+1", 1);
       tzset();
       now = time(NULL);
       //Get the Local time (GMT+1)
       local = localtime(&now);
       printf("Local time and date: %s\n", asctime(local));
       //Get the system time (GMT)
       local = gmtime(&now);
       printf("UTC time and date: %s\n", asctime(local));
       return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Local time and date: Thu Aug  4 14:36:42 2011

UTC time and date: Thu Aug  4 15:36:42 2011
```

Comment: Without "setenv("TZ", "GMT+1", 1);" it works fine. If you are in *nix system, calling export TZ="GMT+1" before running it, same result as yours. Try run 'TZ="GMT+1" date' and you get same result. I have no answer for this, but I'm curious too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed very confusing, but not a bug.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) specifies this :

> If preceded by a '-', the timezone shall be east of the Prime Meridian; otherwise, it shall be west (which may be indicated by an optional preceding '+' ).

So, it's basically the reverse of what you might expect.

Comment: this is a very strange specification :(

Comment: @Kit Ho : I have no idea why they specified it that way. And I agree with you that it's very strange. It's one of the big gotcha's when dealing with time.